# Power to the User! (no, really)

Tags: search-results, url, public-website

I am a non-admin user of a SharePoint site that was designed for the upload of files and websites, then a search by criteria/tags that we attached to it.

I would like to have new and better ways of searching or mapping these resources. Here is my first idea. I appreciate anyone's ideas for helping.

- Create a URL list whereby I could see all of the results from a normal search, but in URL format, like a sitemap for the resources on the site. Please excuse my syntax in this example of one of the searches:

  ```
  http://www.mysharepointsite.com/home/resources/search.asp&topic="interesting"&genre="fiction"&length="short"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean searching large or disparate sources of information, you can build such a URL when you prepare site columns for the properties and crawl and map them to the managed properties (read up on this). They will be available as refiners in the search ui.

Comment: Alexey, are these suggestions available for non-admins like me? Care to share an initial support website URL? This is the first one I found and it seems to infer I would have to enable crawling on the server. I am only a user with credentials to log in and use the web ui.

Comment: Are your servers on premise or in the cloud? which version is your sharepoint?

Comment: In the cloud. I'm not sure of the version. My guess is two versions behind where it should be :/